# Keep getting backorders for certain products even when turned off

Tags: magento-1.7, backorder, out-of-stock, stock-status

My client keeps getting over orders but only for certain products on her Magento store. For example she has one scarf in the stock with the qty set to 1. When purchased All of the settings are set to No Backorders so I cannot understand why this would be happening. I was wondering if anyone has come across this problem before and what they have done to solve this issue.

I am editing this post to add more detail to the problem.

There is only one of this product it has been purchased, after which it is purchased again by someone else and both of the orders go through. The settings are set to no backorders. I do not understand why it is not immediatly going out of stock when it is purchased the first time but will when purchased the second time. The quantity was 100% set to 1 and to go out of stock when at 0. This is happening often on mulitple products but not every time.  Very strange.

Comment: Are these customers who have the item in their baskets already?  Sounds similar to a bug we found: http://www.branded3.com/blogs/magento-core-bug-multiple-basket-items-stock/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to keep into consideration in Magento to allow/disallow backorders. I found this [page](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-enable-backorders/) quite useful, it might help you in this issue.